# Grant higher API access than the login user has

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, oauth

We have a connected app, and a read-only SF user.

I want to get write access to the connected app, which is done by calling `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` with OAuth client ID and secret + the SF user's details.

I got the access token, and can make API queries to list SF objects. When I try to modify a SF object, I receive `{'message': 'entity type cannot be updated: Account', 'errorCode': 'CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY'}` error message, which does not tell directly that there is no permission to preform this action because of lack of granted access, but this is my best guess.

Now I wanted to find out if it's even possible to grant higher (write) API access to the connected app when the authorizer user has only read-only UI right? Is it documented anywhere? Some pages says that by using connected apps, I can restrict API access, which is nice, but now I want the opposite, and so far I didn't read anything about that this would be not allowed.

Comment: `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY` is often a poorly written trigger. Frequent root cause: _when an object has a trigger, and creating or updating records cause that trigger to throw an unhandled exception_ . Regarding your question, the authorization privileges granted to access token issued via connected app are controlled by [scope](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5)

Comment: I don't think this is what Klenium is talking about. Scopes control only the API level access, so in his case whether or not the user coming in through the connected app is allowed to even access ALL object (according to the permission to each object, that the user has). Klenium now wants to add object permission on top --> The read only user logging in via browser only has 'read'. But logging in through the connected app elevates permission to for example 'edit' on Accounts.

Comment: edit: Also your interpretation of the error is wrong in this case. Klenium's guess is spot on.  Missing CRUD is the reason.
There is only this idea-exchange for the functionality:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddU7UAJ/apply-crudfls-permissions-to-connected-apps